# Need a combination of configurable and bundle product type

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, extensions, bundled-product

Hi I need to be able to configure a product like the below example but cannot do it with default Magento products.

Product with SKU 24KE
-With bundled products
-2 different color options (Black: 24KEB, White:24KEW)
When selecting a color option, the SKU must Change to 24KEB OR 24KEW.

Is there any extension or anyway I can do this?

Comment: Do you want bundle product as an option of configurable? If so then it is not possible to do, only simple or virtual product product may be an option of configurable.

Comment: I need a product that will dynamically change SKU when picking a color option. Each color option is a different SKU. This same product must have free bundled items.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand what you try to achieve. There is "bundle product" notion in magento and it has specific meaning. Configurable product is a type of product where you select an attribute(s) which selection points to specific simple product. If you want to have parent configurable sku changed you need to set it to be "dynamic". But if you want to use magento bundle product as an option it is not possible.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can be a little more clear.

I have an item with model# 24KE.
24KE comes in 2 colors... White: 24KEW and Black: 24KEB.
I need a product type that when I choose white, the SKU will change to 24KEW in the order details.
This same product comes with free included items, so I need to be able to include free items as a bundle in this one product.

Comment: I always thought you could use Custom options to change the sku?

Comment: It sort of does but if my SKU is 24KE and I checkout with the white color option it just appends the SKU to 24KE-24KEW. I need it to just change to 24KEW and not append.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with default magento setup. You can create configurable product and use simples as black and white options. This will make order view in admin to display selected option sku as ordered product. But you are not able to add additional product as part of that configurable.

You would need to create a module which would add some ability to link those configurable to additional items and then when one of the children is being added/removed from cart you would programmatically add/remove those additional product. If those additional products cannot increase the price you would need either during addition reduce their price to 0 or create cart price rule for that.

For linking products you could use up-sells or cross-sells if you are not using them right now but automatic addition and price management requires some programming work.

Alternatively you could extend bundle product and allow configurable to be part of them. This would require some frontend changes as you would need to somehow load configurable options on bundle product view.

I do not know of any module that can do that, you can search magento marketplace for some solutions.

**[EDIT]**

I just thought of alternative solution within default setup. You can create a bundle product. Your black and white options from configurable add to one group which will allow only for 1 of them to select. The rest of bundled items add to other group or groups depending on your requirements. From backend you should see all skus of simples on the order level.